# Should I get my Canon DLSR serviced?

Tags: canon, dslr, repair, canon-7d, repair-parts

I got my Canon EOS 7D in India in 2011 and have clicked some great snaps with it. And to be fair, it hasn't given me any trouble since purchase. So much so that I never had to take the camera for repair or any major overhaul.

Apart from a slight decline in photo sharpness over the years, there hasn't been anything majorly wrong with it.

Should I take the camera to the service center for an overhaul? Is there a concept of getting your DSLR serviced? If yes, what should I tell the repair guy, considering that there is nothing really wrong with the Camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't fix something that works.

This is usual practice with (almost) all the things around us. Just keep your batteries charged, replace time to time the SD cards and (depend of the amount of photos you take) be prepared to replace the shutter. I know it is rated for 150000 actuations. But this is for orientation and your may last much longer.

The other thing you should do time to time is to replace date/time battery. But you can do it by yourself. Here is [Canon manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/457678/Canon-Eos-7d.html?page=251), page 251.